# How to resolve merge conflicts on GitHub protected branch.?

Tags: github, pull-request, conflict

I have two deployment branches test and sit. Both are protected branches. Developers creating multiple features branches and merging them with test branch. When I try to create PR PULL REQUEST from test to sit. I faced conflicts. How can I resolve them on protected branch. Also we are pushing changes to sit from test branch only. ( Not any feature branch)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a pull request between two branches and there's a conflict, you have to modify the head branch (that is, the branch from which you are merging) before you can merge.  In this case, you have two protected branches, which means you cannot modify either one.

What you should do in this case is to create an equivalent branch to `test`, say, `test-temp`, perform the merge into `sit` yourself on the command line, and in that merge commit, resolve the conflicts.  Then, push `test-temp` to the remote and merge that instead of `test`.  Your temporary branch won't be subject to the branch protections, since it isn't one of the specifically enumerated branches.

Comment: But i cannot merge any other featured branch to sit except test one. So i am not able to merge test-temp branch to sit.

Comment: GitHub does not prevent you from opening a pull request using an arbitrary branch.  If you have a policy that prevents you from doing that, then you won't be able to accomplish your goal, and the branches will have to remain unmerged in their current state.

Comment: @bk2204We are not preventing pull request from arbitrary branch. Only approver will check whether it's not arbitrary branch or not  before approving pr